# Kafka with Spring Integration - consumer-timeout vs read timeout?

Tags: java, spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

With the configuration

Using the spring-integration-kafka extention  and the following configuration:

```
<int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect"
    zk-connect="#{kafkaConfig['zooKeeperUrl']}" zk-connection-timeout="10000"
    zk-session-timeout="10000" zk-sync-time="2000" />

<int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext" consumer-timeout="5000" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect">
```

the `timeout` is the time of waiting for a message or the time of waiting for a message and reading that message? is this value different from read timeout?

Answer (score 1):

consumer.timeout.ms -1
from [Kafka configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html)

> Throw a timeout exception to the consumer if no message is available
>   for consumption after the specified interval

Comment: ok, but if the timeout is smaller than the time interval in which the message would be read, what happens

Answer (score 0):

from [git-hub-spring-integration-kafka-repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka)

"In the above consumer context, you can also specify a consumer-timeout value which would be used to timeout the consumer in case of no messages to consume. This timeout would be applicable to all the streams (threads) in the consumer. The default value for this in Kafka is -1 which would make it wait indefinitely. However, Sping Integration overrides it to be 5 seconds by default in order to make sure that no threads are blocking indefinitely in the lifecycle of the application and thereby giving them a chance to free up any resources or locks that they hold. It is recommended to override this value so as to meet any specific use case requirements. By providing a reasonable consumer-timeout on the context and a fixed-delay value on the poller, this inbound adapter is capable of simulating a message driven behaviour."

Comment: so, if I have consumer-timeout=1 and the message can be read in 1000 because it is very large...what happens?

Comment: this property has nothing to do with the size of the message

Comment: if the size of the message is veeeery big, the reading that message will take a lot of time

Comment: what would be a very big message for you? can you be a little more specific on your questions?

Comment: let's say that reading an entire message takes 10 seconds. If I set the consumer timeout to be 1 second, will it still read the message?

Comment: the poll timeout is the time that the consumer will wait for records, is not the time that it will spend reading. The result set may be empty, but kafka will read and cache that value anyway, the thing is that you will have to poll twice or 3-times to get that file. Either way for most cases you will be fine, kafka is pretty fast reading big files.

Comment: "but kafka will read and cache that value anyway, the thing is that you will have to poll twice or 3-times to get that file" - I have to programatically poll multiple times or does it know how to compose the entire result by itself? Do you happen to have around a documentation about that so I can read further? it would be very useful:)

Comment: I have read it before, but I did not find this particular detail - maybe you can give a keyword, or the section?